# How to achieve formatting like this in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a function formatted like this:

```
private void verifyDatatypeTables(
        final DynamoDBMapper mapper,
        final List<Datatype> datatypeMissingEntries) {
        final List<Datatype> datatypeEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        this.mapToListDatatypeTables(datatypeEntries);
        final List<Datatype> datatypeEntriesInTable =
            this.dbUtilityDatatype.scanRecord(new DynamoDBScanExpression(), true);
    }
```

This creates a little reading problem. I want it to be formatted like this:

```
private void verifyDatatypeTables(
        final DynamoDBMapper mapper,
        final List<Datatype> datatypeMissingEntries
 ) {
        final List<Datatype> datatypeEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        this.mapToListDatatypeTables(datatypeEntries);
        final List<Datatype> datatypeEntriesInTable =
            this.dbUtilityDatatype.scanRecord(new DynamoDBScanExpression(), true);
    }
```

How to achieve formatting like this in Eclipse?

Comment: Isn't the function body and closing `}` just indented too far?

Comment: That is indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> edit -> Parentheses -> Method declaration -> separate lines
```

with

```
Line Wrapping -> Method declarations -> Parameters -> Line Wrapping policy -> Wrap all elements, every element on a new line
```